# Collections subtypes - Liskov Substitution Principle

Tags: java, collections, liskov-substitution-principle, subtyping

Java does not permit `Collection<Car>` as a subtype of `Collection<Vehicle>`. Is this because `Collection<Car>` cannot be used in place of every `Collection<Vehicle>` as the `Collection<Vehicle>` could contain elements which are other subtypes of Vehicle such as Motorbike, therefore it violates Liskov substitution principle?

Comment: This is more related to the invariance challenge in using generics and the covariance response that goes with it

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `Collection`s violate the Liskov substitution principle due to the existence of “optional operations”, i.e. the mutation methods may be unusable for a particular implementation.

Regarding the type safety, however, it works that way:

Assuming that `Car` is a subtype of `Vehicle`, a `Collection<Car>` is a type that allows an operation like

```
Collection<Car> c=…;
Car car=c.iterator().next();
```

which `Collection<Vehicle>` doesn’t. On the other hand, `Collection<Vehicle>` is a type that allows an operation like

```
Collection<Vehicle> c=…;
Vehicle v=…;
c.add(v);
```

which `Collection<Car>` doesn’t. Therefore, neither of these `Collection` types is a subtype of the other.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050848/do-collections-unmodifiablexxx-methods-violate-lsp for a debate on whether collection mutation methods violate LSP.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. The other way around:

That a `Collection<Car>` only contains `Car`s is fine, even though a `Collection<Vehicle>` might contain other types of vehicles. You can still give a `Collection<Car>` to anyone who can handle elements from a `Collection<Vehicle>`.

But `Collection<Car>` cannot be used in place of a `Collection<Vehicle>`, because you could put a `Bicycle` into a `Collection<Vehicle>` (but not in a `Collection<Car>`). So you cannot give the `Collection<Car>` to someone who wants to collect vehicles.

Answer (score 0):

`Collection<T>` is a type constructor, so `Collection<Car>` is a type and `Collection<Vehicle>` is another type.

Now the question, if a `Collection<Car>` can be used where a `Collection<Vehicle>` is required, is a matter of variance (co-variance is this case).

Liskov substitution principle exceed type conformity in a way that it not only requires to provide more, require less, but also that the contract of the supertype is kept, [see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle#Principle).

Answer (score 0):

Note that a `Collection<Car>` is *invariant* over the component type `Car`. So if you want to use a collection of vehicles which could be cars, bikes, trains, etc., you should take a *covariant* collection `Collection<? extends Vehicle>`.

Of course, if you have a `CarFactory` with a produce method that should park the produced cars somewhere, a *contravariant* `produce(Collection<? super Car>)` method would be the most useful implementation.