# Liskov substitution principle and Interface

Tags: c#, interface, liskov-substitution-principle

Does the `ICollection<T>.Add()`-implementation of arrays break the Liskov substitution principle? The method results in a `NotSupportedException`, which does break the LSP, IMHO.

```
string[] data = new string[] {"a"};
ICollection<string> dataCollection = data;
dataCollection.Add("b");
```

This results in

> Unhandled exception: System.NotSupportedException: Collection was of
>   a fixed size.

I found a pretty similar question concerning `Stream`-implementations. I open a separate question, because this case is pretty different: [Liskov substitution principle and Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290834/liskov-substitution-principle-and-streams).
The difference here is that `ICollection` does not provide a `CanAdd`-Property or such thing, as the `Stream`-class does.

Comment: Types can't violate LSP on their own, it's only subtypes which can fail to be substitutable with their supertypes. `ICollection<T>.Add` is ugly but it does document that `NotSupportedException` will be thrown if `IsReadOnly` is false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see why you'd think so. There's a function that expects a collection, and it expects it to be modifiable. Passing an array will make it fail, so clearly you can't substitute the interface with this particular implementation, right?

Is it a problem? Maybe. It depends on how often you expect ideals to hold. Are you going to use an array instead of a collection by accident and then be surprised ten years later that it breaks down? Not really. The type system .NET applications use isn't perfect - it doesn't tell you this particular `ICollection<T>` usage requires the collection to be modifiable.

Would .NET be better off if arrays didn't pretend to implement `ICollection<T>` (or `IEnumerable<T>`, which they also don't "really" implement)? I don't think so. Is there a way to keep the convenience of arrays "being" `ICollection<T>` that would also avoid the same LSP violation? Nope. The underlying array would still be fixed-length - at best, you'd be violating more useful principles instead (like the fact that reference types are not expected to have referential transparency).

But wait! Let's look at the actual contract of `ICollection<T>.Add`. Does it allow for a `NotSupportedException` to be thrown? Oh yes - quoting MSDN:

> [NotSupportedException is thrown if ...] The ICollection is read-only.

And arrays do return true when you query `IsReadOnly`. The contract is upheld.

If you consider `Stream` not to break LSP because of `CanWrite`, you *must* consider arrays to be valid collections, since they have `IsReadOnly`, and it is `true`. If a function accepts a read-only collection and tries adding to it, it's an error in the function. There's no way to specify this explicitly in C#/.NET, so you have to rely on other parts of the contract than just types - e.g. the documentation for the function should specify that a `NotSupportedException` (or `ArgumentException` or whatever) is thrown for a collection that is readonly. A good implementation would do this test right at the start of the function.

One important thing to note is that types aren't quite as constrained in C# as in the type theory where LSP is defined. For example, you can write a function like this in C#:

```
bool IsFrob(object bobicator)
{
  return ((Bob)bobicator).IsFrob;
}
```

Can `bobicator` be substituted with any supertype of `object`? Clearly not. But it just as clearly isn't a problem of the poor `Frobinate` type - it's an error in the `IsFrob` function. In practice, a lot of code in C# (and most other languages) only works with objects far more constrained than would be indicated by the type in the method signature.

An object only violates the LSP if it violates the contract of its supertype. It cannot be responsible for *other* code violationg LSP. And often you'll find it quite pragmatic to make code that doesn't *perfectly* hold up under LSP - engineering is, and always has been, about trade-offs. Weigh the costs carefuly.

Answer (score 2):

No, as it's not a class - the relationship between an interface and the implementing class is not the same as the relationship between super and subclass.

LSP specifically applies to behaviour of code which implies implementation - an interface has no implementation so LSP does not apply.

It is, however, a violation of the **Interface Segregation Principle** which says that you should rather compose interfaces to avoid unimplemented methods.

Comment: It's true that LSP was defined in the context of subtyping; however, I'm not quite sure if that's a valid argument. Is it supposed to be bad when a subtype cannot replace a supertype, but OK when an implementation of an interface cannot replace the interface? You're right it's a violation of ISP, but there's no way to resolve that in C#/.NET - you can't take an existing interface and split it into multiple interfaces.

Comment: @DarrenYoung - You wouldn't 'by definition' because `ICollection<T>.Add` is only valid if `IsReadOnly` returns `false`, while arrays return `true`.

Comment: @Luaan: Interfaces (method contracts) do not define behaviour, only implementation does and implementation can only be provided by a class. Therefore LSP cannot apply because the principle specifically applies to behaviour.

Comment: Yes, in a strict type-theory sense. But programming is more than just what's defined by the type system - interfaces don't have behaviours in theory, but their contracts (e.g. documentation) might describe valid and invalid behaviours for an interface. There's more to the interface contract than just the names and types of the methods. That's why I didn't downvote or upvote your answer - I honestly can't decide whether it's worth it to consider the theory when the question is plainly about coding, where all of these things are much less clear-cut than in the theory.

Comment: Rather, the `ICollection<T>` interface is badly designed code from Microsoft because it doesn't apply the principles correctly - the debate exists only because this particular interface is part of the framework. Anywhere else it would've been called a bad implementation and noted for change. I don't disagree on pragmatism but on base principles you don't compromise if you can change the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252363/does-liskov-substitution-principle-also-apply-to-classes-implementing-interfaces this answer suggest that Liskov principle apply both to interface and sub-classes, indeed it applies every time the relationship is "is-a"